# Change theme-color via JavaScript (mobile chrome tab color)

Tags: javascript, html, colors, hex

I wanted to create a hex color clock that changes the background color of the site + the theme-color (mobile chrome tab color).
The clock with the changing background is working, the theme-color on the other hand is not changing.

This is what I got so far.

```
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
      <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
      <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
      <title>Hex Clock</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="absolute-center">
      <p id="hex"></p>
      <div>
      <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

```
var hexColor = document.getElementById('hex');
var time = new Date();
var hours = time.getHours().toString();
var minutes = time.getMinutes().toString();
var seconds = time.getSeconds().toString();
var hexColorStr = '#' + hours + minutes + seconds;
var metaThemeColor = document.querySelector("meta[name=theme-color]");

function hexClock() {


  if (hours.length < 2) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }

  if (minutes.length < 2) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (seconds.length < 2) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  }


  metaThemeColor.setAttribute("content", hexColorStr);
  hexColor.textContent = hexColorStr;
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = hexColorStr;
}

hexClock();
setInterval(hexClock, 1000);
```

I tried this code https://gordonlesti.com/change-theme-color-via-javascript/, it worked by it self but as soon as I implemented it in my code it stopped working.

Comment: Hey, i found this link. Can you check here https://gordonlesti.com/change-theme-color-via-javascript/

Comment: that's the one I tried but I can't find my mistake.

Comment: Oh i see, let's look for more examples, I can't see any difference either :)